# Dynamically creating the config file by using tokenized file

Tags: c#, tfs, web-config, config, app-config

In our developmet proccess we are using CI/CD tools of TFS.
To create config files for different machines we're using tools: XDT Transform and Replace Tokens
So by using those tools we transform sample config file => config file for specific machine

For example:

These

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <Param name="par_1" scenario="123" value =""/>
      </configuration>
```

Transforms to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <Param name="par_1" scenario="123" value ="token_value"/>
      </configuration>
```

By Using these tokenized file with preloaded token #{test}# = token_value

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
        <Param name="par_1" scenario="123" value ="#{test}#" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator = "Match(name, scenario)"/>
</configuration>
```

The Question is: Can I transform not only attributes, but the text value?

Example:

```
<Param name="par2">TEST</Param>
```

Can I transform Text value TEST by using those tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dynamically creating the config file by using tokenized file

The answer is yes.

As test with [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task, I add following code in my `web.config` file:

```
</configuration>
  <Param name="par2">#{Test}#</Param>
</configuration>
```

Then add the variable `test` with test value `123` in the Variables:

[image]

Then use the Replace Tokens task to replace the `#{Test}#`:

The test result:

```
<Param name="par2">123</Param>
```

So, you could transform not only attributes, but also the text value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, but if I want to use this attribute `xdt:Locator = "Match(name, scenario)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" ` to find param that I want to change 

**What should I put into Transform?**

Comment: @DavidNaik, You mean you want to use `xdt:Locator = "Match(name, scenario)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"` to find the text value in `<Param name="par2">TEST</Param>`? Am I right? If yes, I am afraid not. If not, could you please give me a simple sample about what you do to do?

Comment: Yeah, you right. That's the whole question was about:)

Thanks for help!